# Is there a third-party or native methodology for pushing/pulling data to/from Excel to specific Salesforce Objects?

Tags: excel, salesforceexcelconnector

Our desired workflow is as follows:
1. Creation of quote data for a specific project within Excel using a template containing a myriad of formulas necessary to accommodate technical selling.
2.  Specific data (line item prices, product types, project duration) is pushed/pulled to/from a specific Opportunity within Salesforce through a native interface - either Excel or Salesforce.

I have found many third-party apps and tools that permit some sort of import functionality, but most are cumbersome, are designed for managing large data sets and reporting, and would not be supported by our sales team.

Comment: doesnt using excel contradicts the use of CRM in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Well I kinda agree with Pranay that using excel instead of Salesforce is kinda... interesting idea.

But to the point

There are many ETL tools that can meet your requirements but still you'll need always give some effort to achieve results.

Personally I've used Pentaho, which have also Salesforce connector, but I've ended with creating CSV files for specific objects and later used Data Loader to load the data. Everything can be automated though especially with premium version.

Another one is Talend whith which you can achieve basically the same results.

Ultimate solution though is to use Salesforce from the beginning.

Comment: Our quoting process demands the use of a workbook nine sheets long, with complex calculations. "Just put it in Salesforce" is not a viable option to my knowledge.

Comment: Therefore I've presented you alternatives :) Although still in long run using Salesforce CPQ would probably reduce steps/work/mistakes/time used when running those excel sheets. I definitely agree that it would not be easy but in the end you have CRM with CPQ capabilities for something eh?